# Close single vim instance when I have multiple open

Tags: linux, vim

I did `vim *` to simultaneously open 3 text files, as I would with any other application. However, when I use `:q` to close the first file, it does not close, and instead says `E173: 2 more files to edit`. How can I fix this so that I can access each file, and then close the whole thing?

Comment: You might try asking this over at [Vi and Vim.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Vi questions aren't off-topic here but it's not the *best* site to ask on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have multiple instances of vim, just a single one with three buffers.

Use `:n` to close the first file and go to the next, or `:wn` to save and go next. `:prev` goes backwards.

You can also use `:2b` to jump to buffer #2, and/or set up a plugin like MiniBufExpl to show a list of currently opened files for easier navigation.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't clear with my question, but you got half of what I was trying to ask!

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities that I can think of:

- simply run <kbd>:q</kbd> again, vi will close
- run <kbd>:qa</kbd> (quit, all)

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't clear with my question, but you got half of what I was trying to ask!